# Drawing upscaled image with no smoothing

Tags: c#, image, xna

I want to draw a texture2d 5 times larger than original with no smoothing.

Drawing line:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2(0, 0), null, Color.White, 0, Vector2.Zero,
5f, SpriteEffects.None, 0);
```

The result is a scaled smoothed image. Adding `this.GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.PointClamp;` doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is Point Texture filtering. Look [here](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/68599/418734.aspx).